# How can I alternate column headers in a tab delimited file?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a tab delimited txt file and i need to switch first and second column names (without switching columns data). In other words I need to rename A(Id) to B(ExternalId) and B(ExternalId) to A(Id). Other columns in the file (other data) should stay unchanged. I'm very new in PowerShell, please advice. As I understand I need to use import/export csv cmdlet.

I tryed this, but it's not working the right way...

```
Import-Csv 'C:\original_users.txt' | 
    Select-Object Id, @{Name="ExternalId";Expression={$_."Id"}}; Select-Object ExternalId, @{Name="Id";Expression={$_."ExternalId"}} | 
    Export-Csv 'C:\changed_users.txt'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Import-CSV` and `Export-CSV` cmdlets have their strengths but this might not be one of them. The latter cmdlet would introduce quoting that might not be in your original file and that might not be desired.

Either way why not just do some text manipulation on the first line! Lets read in the file and and output the first lined, edited, and the remainder of the file. This sample uses a new location but you could easily write it back to the same file.

```
# Get the full file into a variable
$fullFile = Get-Content "c:\temp\mockdata.csv"

# Parse the first line into a column array
$columns = $fullFile[0].Split("`t")

# Rebuild the header by switching the columns order as desired. 
$newHeader = ($columns[1],$columns[0] + ($columns | Select-Object -Skip 2)) -join "`t"

# Write the header back to file then the rest of the data.
$outputPath = "C:\somepath.txt"

$newHeader | Set-Content $outputPath
$fullFile | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Add-Content $outputPath
```

This also preserves the presence of other columns and their data.

Comment: Thank you! You are the best :)